# Perfect squares using 20 1's, 20 2's and 20 3's.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many perfect squares can be formed using 20  1's, 20  2's and 20  3's. This is a recent exam question, which I had no clue how to solve?

There is some kind of trick here, since time allotted to solve it was just 4 minutes.

Comment: All $60$ digits? None.

Comment: That's what I thought too, Ivan, but apparently from looking at the answers the question means "formed by addition using ...".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Hint:** The resulting number is divisible by $3$ but not by $9$, since the digit sum is $120$.

Comment: Thanks! Looks too simple now. But still I couldn't have figured it out in the exam.

Comment: Well, maybe you could now. It looks as if the criterion for divisibility by $3$, by $9$ is part of the curriculum. Ideas tend to repeat themselves on exams.

Answer (score 13):

How about this:  $$\begin {array} &1&2&3&1&2&3&1&2&3&1&2&3&1&2&3&1\\
2&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&2\\
3&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&3\\
1&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&1\\
2&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&2\\
3&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&3\\
1&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&1\\
2&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&2\\
3&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&3\\
1&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&1\\
2&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&2\\
3&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&3\\
1&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&1\\
2&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&2\\
3&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&3\\
1&2&3&1&2&3&1&2&3&1&2&3&1&2&3&1\\
\end {array}$$
If done in a properly spaced font, it looks like a perfect square to me.  The sum along each side is the same

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{array}{ll}
    20 *1 &= 20 \\
    20 *2 &= 40 \\
    20 *3 &= 60 \\
    ---------------
 \text{total} &= 120
 \end{array}
```

Now, Perfect square(s)...
$1+4+9+16+25+36+49 = 140$ ( I can remove $2$ number with total of $20$ ($4+16$))

that will lead to

$1+9+25+36+49$ (i.e. $5$ numbers)

Answer: $5$ perfect squares can be formed..